# Execute Linux System Command from CoDeSys Runtime

Tags: plc, st, codesys

I am attempting to resolve a bug where the memory on my PLC is not synced on an operating system level. When power is cycled to the PLC a file I have "on disk" doesn't save when the PLC boots up again. I have found that running the linux `sync` command before the power cycle resolves this issue. How do I run a Linux command (in this case, the `sync` command) from inside of CoDeSys?

Answer (score 1):

According to Cross Control, CoDeSys does not have a native way to make a system call. You have to rely on proprietary libraries for your specific PLC.